# Manually compiling Sass in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm manually compiling Sass in a Rails 4.2 app, and I'm running into issue with Sass' @import.  It's giving me the following error - "File to import not found or unreadable..."    Here's a code snippet.

```
scheme_css_dir = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/schemes/#{scheme}/css"
template = File.read("#{scheme_css_dir}/styles.css.scss")

engine = Sass::Engine.new(template, { 
  :syntax => :scss,
  :cache => false,
  :read_cache => false,
  :style => :compressed,
  :load_paths => [scheme_css_dir]
})
output = engine.render
```

styles.css.scss contains several @import statements, and it's failing on the first one.  Here's what the first one looks like.

```
@import "./flexslider";
```

There is a flexslider.css.scss file in the same directory as style.css.scss.  I'm supplying that directory in the :load_paths option.  Interestingly enough, if I change the @import line to...

```
@import "./flexslider.css.scss";
```

...then it gets to the next @import line in the file - where it throws the same error.  This style.css.scss manifest complies successfully during deploy as is (without adding extensions to all the @imports).

What am I missing?  Is there additional config that I need in order to use Sass::Engine to compile css manifest just like Rails would during deploy?

FYI - I'm using the latest version of sass-rails (5.0.3).

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**  Thanks to papirtiger's comment, I was able to resolve the issue with @import by updated the extensions of my files from .css.scss to .scss.  However, I'm still running into errors with asset helpers - specifically image-url and font-url.  Here's the error I'm seeing...

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

The error occurs in a sprockets_context method in sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb

```
def sprockets_context
  options[:sprockets][:context]
end
```

Any thoughts on how to get pass this hurdle?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to be able to do this.  When you use Sass outside of Rails, you're not supposed to add the `.css` extension, you're only supposed to use the `.scss` or `.sass` extensions.

Comment: Just use some tool to batch rename your files. Sass just assumes your files have the `.scss` extension - and there even if there an option get sass to look for `.css.scss` its a good idea to change anyways since Sprockets has/will be removing support for  `.css.scss`.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/290

Comment: Here's an issue on sass-rails that describes what I'm needing - https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/208.  I haven't found any record of Sass' engine accepting a helper module as an arg in the constructor.

Comment: did you find a fix for `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`?